# Draw Graph in android?

Tags: java, android

i want to draw a graph same like the image below. can any body suggest me how to draw this graph. i already use open chart time graph library but i cant't draw this type of graph. 
like: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/1856369**

[image]

> Blockquote

My code:-

public class ChartExample extends Activity {

```
private GraphicalView mChart;

RelativeLayout chartContainer;
ModalDate modaldate;
private String strDate, strWeight, strHight;
Calendar calendar;
Date date2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    openChart();

}

private void openChart() {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    Date date;
    int doubleWeight, doubleHeight;

    // Creating TimeSeries for Visits
    TimeSeries visitsSeries = new TimeSeries("Visits");

    // Creating TimeSeries for Views
    TimeSeries viewsSeries = new TimeSeries("Views");
    /*
     * for (int i = 0; i < DateList.getInstance().size(); i++) { ModalDate
     * modaldate = new ModalDate(); ModalEntries entries = new
     * ModalEntries(); strDate = modaldate.getDate().toString(); strHeight =
     * modaldate.getModalentries().get(i).getHeight(); strWeight =
     * modaldate.getModalentries().get(i).getHeight();
     */

    for (int i = 0; i < DateList.getInstance().size(); i++) {

        strDate = DateList.getInstance().get(i).getDate();
        strWeight = DateList.getInstance().get(i).getModalentries().get(i)
                .getHeight();
        strHight = DateList.getInstance().get(i).getModalentries().get(i)
                .getWeight();
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(strDate);
            calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            date2 = calendar.getTime();
            doubleHeight = Integer.parseInt(strHight);
            doubleWeight = Integer.parseInt(strWeight);
            visitsSeries.add(date2, doubleHeight);
            viewsSeries.add(date2, doubleWeight);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);

    // Adding Visits Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(viewsSeries);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(5);
    visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize viewsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer viewsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    viewsRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    viewsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    viewsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    viewsRenderer.setLineWidth(5);
    viewsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Child Graph");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Date");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Value");
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(viewsRenderer);
    // Creating a Time Chart
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(
            getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, "dd-MMM-yyyy");

    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    // Setting a click event listener for the graph
    chartContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
    chartContainer.removeAllViews();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    chartContainer.addView(mChart, lay);

    // chartContainer.addView(mChart);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        finish();

    }

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        openChart();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        finish();
    }
}
enter code here
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/1856369 it may help you.

Comment: how can i draw date line in time openchart graph.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following alternative 
http://androidplot.com/

Comment: How can i draw date line like 15 dec and other??

Comment: read up the doc there and be creative , isn't this is what we programmer are supposed to do , no straight and simple solution to all the problems

Comment: thanks for your support but i have some problem to create date lines on graph. as you see on image.

Comment: or should i use canvas to draw this graph?

Comment: I think this is possible on canvas , once you determine the max of X,Y using onmeasure ,you could determine what is the "scale" you  need for the Y-axis , get your max value ie 85cm minus the low 65cm for example  , over the range of the Y-axis scale interval , you could figure out the ratio , may be  use moveTO to plot the xy line , this will take a lot of patience and plan  , as you also need to draw the vertical line for the date as well.